# Making http Post request on Gupshup IDE works?

Tags: http, post, gupshup

I copied gupshup's document code and modified just url as "http://posttestserver.com/post.php" and it doesn't work.

Anyone has an advice for me?

```
else if(event.message.toLowerCase() == "post") {
    var contextParam = {
        "User": {
        "userName": "sbCobxxxx",
        "Password": "xxxxxxx-9f-4307-9d9a-451f3xxxx075",
        "Pin": "16776"
    }
    };
    var url = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php";
    var param = JSON.stringify(contextParam);
    var header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
    context.simplehttp.makePost(url, param, header);
}

function HttpResponseHandler(context, event) {
    // if(event.geturl === "http://ip-api.com/json")
    context.sendResponse(event.getresp);
}
```

Response returns empty string: ""

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing using Gupshup's emulator? If yes then POST and GET calls with headers and params doesn't work in the emulator as of now. The [documentations](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/emulator-console-logs) mentions it. However, you can deploy the code and test it out using [Gupshup proxy bot](https://www.messenger.com/t/gupshupproxybot) on Facebook messenger and it will work fine.
Here is a screenshot of the testing I did after directly copying your code into the IDE.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed it.