# Gupshup Post - Empty Body

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, gupshup

I'm building a simple bot that makes an http post call passing in JSON objects. The server responds back with the error - {"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}:

I don't think the server side is the issue; I've tried the request using httpie.

The code in Gupshup

```
var contextParam = {
    "botname": event.botname, 
    "channel": event.channel, 
    "sender": event.sender,
    "message":event.message
};
var url = "https://abcserver.com/sm/postData";
var param = JSON.stringify(contextParam);
var header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
context.simplehttp.makePost(url, param, header)
```

The corresponding call from httpie

```
http POST https://abcserver.com/sm/postData  botname=MrBot channel=Skype sender=MrSender message=Hi
```

At the server side:

```
logger.debug("Request body : " + str(request.body))
```

puts -  `"Request body : b'"` in the log file.

PS: I'm using Django, Django Rest Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Answer Update** 21/8/2017]

The syntax for making the HTTP POST call using the IDE Bot Builder of Gupshup is correct. Check out this post [making-http-post-request-on-gupshup-ide-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134776/making-http-post-request-on-gupshup-ide-works) on SO where a working code is present.

Complete working code:

```
 var url_ = 'http://p-curl-i.herokuapp.com/getresponse/';
var body = {
    "botname": event.botname,
    "channel": event.channel,
    "sender": event.sender,
    "message": event.message
};
  var headers = {
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length' : JSON.stringify(body).length 
};
   context.simplehttp.makePost(url_, JSON.stringify(body), headers);
```

You need to send "Content-Length" because your server has this as mandatory and Gupshup's backend is not sending the content length by default as Postman or httpie does.

Comment: The serverside works with httpie and postman as expected, but has a problem when the request comes from gupshup. any thoughts?

Comment: is it possible for you to share the details of the API or the Postman curl command for me to test? If not here then you can write to us on developer@gupshup.io